# What is the best practice with JMS Servers? Should it be deployed on Consumer or Producer side?

Tags: jboss, jms, weblogic, integration, message-queue

From architecture point of view, I was wondering what would be the best practice on an integration scenario with 2 application and OSB as Middleware: JMS Consumer runs over JBoss while OSB application encapsulates a service provider. Should JMS Queues reside on the JBoss (foreign server) or on WebLogic Server? That is, If I get to choose, JMS Server should be on consumer or producer side? What would be the pros and cons?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, you can create a foreign destination in your web logic server that connects to the producer queue in the producer end. In this arrangement your consumer will listen in the local end of the foreign destination that connects to the producer queue.

I can think of the following benefits:

A> Foreign Destinations are mapped to WebLogic JNDI tree, any MDB that you deploy to the server can simply reference the remote destination using its local JNDI name.

B> As you are directly communicating with the remote resource there is no lag / latency in delivery etc.

C> One issue maybe you will not be able to produce messages in the consuming end because this user may not have enqueue access to the queue. But it all depends on your setup. This maybe required for some cases like testing etc.